# display Hashmap return values one at a time random

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display one item at a time randomly inside a textview. I can display all of them with the below code.

```
final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
   // for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap


    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE,parser.getValue(element, KEY_TITLE));



        menuItems.add(map);

        List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values()); 
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(valuesList.size()); 
       randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex); 
       Log.i("inside", randomValue);    
    }

     Collections.shuffle(menuItems);
     menuItems.add(map);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.i("outide",map.get(KEY_TITLE));    
                 myImage.setImageResource(imageArr[rgenerator.nextInt(imageArr.length)]);
            }
     });




 }
 }
```

Can any body tell me what's the easiest way to display the data randomly?

Thanks,

Hi Guys,

This is what I came up with which seems to work like I want it to.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(responseBody);
     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
       // for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_TITLE,parser.getValue(element, KEY_TITLE));


            menuItems.add(map);
          }


     Collections.shuffle(menuItems);
     Map<String, String> myValueMap = menuItems.get(0); 
     textView.setText(myValueMap.get(KEY_TITLE));
                next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Collections.shuffle(menuItems);
                     Map<String, String> MapBtn = menuItems.get(0);
                       textView.setText(MapBtn.get(KEY_TITLE));
                        myImage.setImageResource(imageArr[rgenerator.nextInt(imageArr.length)]);
            }
         });

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to randomize the list with

```
Collections.shuffle(menuItems);
```

after the loop

Comment: I added the collections after loop, see revision.